# can't update MYSQL startup settings in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, mysql

I updated to mysql 5.5 and noticed that the server wasn't starting anymore at boot but I had to do it manually. 
It is actually not set to start at any level.

So I did

```
chkconfig -s mysql 2345
```

but I get all these errors

```
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'apport' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface-security' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hostname' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'vsftpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service sysklogd and hwclock if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service sysklogd at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service sysklogd and hwclock if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop between service sysklogd and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service sysklogd at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
/sbin/insserv failed, exit code 1
```

The strange thing is that I tried to do the same with openvpn but It worked with no errors.
How to fix it?